# How does kernel probe drivers

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

when the kernel boots (specifically  on an arm based device) , how does it known which devices are connected to it and what drivers to probe ? can you please refer kernel source or give an example.... Thanks

Comment: I don't see this question as off topic so it's a shame it's marked as such and I can't add full answer. You can read about it for example in LDD3 book, chapter "The Linux Device Model", section "Buses, Devices, and Drivers". Briefly, Linux uses abstractions of `Buses` (like PCI, USB, etc) to which `Devices` can be connected. Each `Device` may be supported by some `Drivers` which have `probe` callback defined. Buses will call those callbacks until some `Driver` decides it will handle this device. Buses may use some hints (like device id) to ask specific `Drivers` or can iterate over all of them

Comment: Also some devices, especially on embedded systems (like ARM systems) are not connected to any real buses that can detect hardware. Such devices are organized in special abstract bus in Linux, called "platform". In old days, registration of drivers for this bus was hardcoded in kernel code but right now it's mostly described by special configuration files, called `Device tree`, that is supplied to kernel by bootloader. The description is still static but it's independent from the kernel code so you can have multiple configurations (for slightly different boards) for one kernel image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel will comes to know that the device is connected through it's device drivers only. The list of device drivers loaded based on the configuration of the Linux kernel.

When a driver is enabled during compilation of the Linux kernel, driver's init section will be placed on special section of kernel image.

During the kernel initialization process in [start_kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L492)(), the static device drivers will be [loaded one by one](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L856).

References about init call mechanism in Linux kernel

http://linuxgazette.net/157/amurray.html 
http://lwn.net/Articles/141730/